# Processing CRUD events in event driven pipeline

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, event-driven-design

I am converting a monolithic application which was handling CRUD events into multiple microservices. Each microservice being designed as kafka stream with specific function. Idea was to allow scaling each microservice individually.
The challenge is, there is a difference in the processing flow of Create and update events where Create event has to go through multiple functional microservices( filtering, enriching) in the pipeline where as update event need not go through these processors. But in order to process the create and update event in order, update events also have to flow through all the microservices( read/write from kafka topics)if not update event can get published even before create event is processed.

```
event publisher(create/update event) =>(kafka topic)=> filter =>(kafka topic)=> enrichment=>..=>...=>(output topic)
```

Is this solution ok to have dummy pipe/service for update event flow to achieve ordering?

Another approach is, instead of designing each microservice as kafka stream, i create each microservice with a synchronous rest interface and call it from a single kafka stream application which can then manage the order of processing create and update events.

```
event publisher(create/update event) =>(kafka topic)=> event processor=>(output topic)
```

where event processor invoked each functional microservice with rest interface.
In this case, although i still achieve separate microservice for each function which can scale individually, invoking the rest calls inside an async streaming application might impact its scalability and other potential problems.

Any comments/suggestion on both the approaches and any alternative approach recommendation would help.